# Активация чекбокса на второй странице при нажатии на чекбокс на первой странице

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, события

Помогите пожалуйста реализовать следующую задачку. Есть 2 страницы и в каждой по одному чекбоксу. Необходимо при нажатии на чекбокс на первой странице активировать чекбокс на второй странице и наоборот. Сайт написан на PHP, url адреса страниц известны, get параметром туда передаются айдишники

Answer (score 1):

В качестве примера.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" > Страница 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2" > Страница 2<br>
<script>
    // Для первой страницы
    document.querySelector('.checkbox').onclick = function() {
        localStorage.setItem('page1Selected', this.checked);
    }

    // На второй странице
    window.onload = function(){
        var check = localStorage.getItem('page1Selected');
        if(check && check == 'true')
            document.querySelector('.checkbox2').checked = true;
    }
</script>
```